# Is it possible to "shoot the fuel tank" of cars?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I remember in GTA4 it was possible to shoot the fuel caps on the side of cars to result in an insta-explosion. As yet, I've not found a way to blow up a car so effectively in GTA5 uing just small arms.

... Is this possible?

Comment: It might be, but I haven't been able to see those caps in *GTA 5*. I do remember seeing a police car exploding after shooting at it for a bit, so I might have hit the invisible cap without knowing it. Or maybe it was scripted to happen, since it was the prologue.

Comment: Usually hitting the back end of cars works. It takes a couple shots. Area of focus is above right if the back tire section.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

well, the answer is *yes **and** no*.

The **YES** part:

- You can "shoot the fuel tank"

The **NO** part:

- The car will not blow up instantly as in *GTA:SA*(never played 4). It will instead create a gas trail that can be ignited

[IGN](http://www.ign.com/) has recently published a list of [*100 Little Things in GTA 5 That Will Blow Your Mind*](http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/09/30/100-little-things-in-gta-5-that-will-blow-your-mind) and #64 says:

> 64) Shooting a car’s gas tank will create a gas trail that can then be
>   ignited.

Comment: Also if you shoot the corner of the chases in front of left rear tire 5-6 times (depends on power of the weapon), the car will blow up. Also shooting the front grill of the vehicle will set it on fire and eventually blow up.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this YouTube video on How to shoot gas tanks in GTA Online. There isn't a gas trail online, but you can still blow up cars much faster shooting them in front of the rear wheel well on the appropriate side.

The video shows the player shooting a few different types of cars in a few different spots, to illustrate the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily one-shot a car in GTA-Online with the revolver if you shoot over the back left tire in the tire well.

Comment: Thank you for contributing but, that's not what OP asked.

Comment: I think this does answer the question, because "over the back left tire in the tire well" is where a car's gas tank is located (as far as GTA 5 is concerned), and the revolver wasn't added to the game until Dec. 2015, so this _is_ a new, useful, and relevant answer to the question.